React Custom Hook executes too many times (or Component renders too many times?) before throwing Minified Error #185
I have a React Component Footer that uses a Custom Hook useLogoImageUrl that seems to be executed 51 times before throwing the following Minified React Error:

Error: Minified React error #185; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=185 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

which states that:

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

The Footer.js in question:
import { useLogoImageUrl } from '../../../src/hooks/useLogoImageUrl';

const Item = ({ item }) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
        <strong>{item.title}</strong>
        {item.children?.length > 0 && (
            <ul>
                {item.children.map(subitem => (
                    <li key={subitem.id}>
                        <a href={subitem.url}>{subitem.title}</a>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        )}
    </div>
);

/**
 * Global Footer Component
 *
 * @param {Object} params
 * @param {string} params.logoImageUrl
 * @param {Array|null} params.menu
 * @param {string} params.instagramLink
 * @param {string} params.youtubeLink
 * ...
 * @param {string} params.sitemapLink
 * ...
 */
export const Footer = ({
    menu = [],
    logoImageUrl,
    instagramLink,
    // ...
    sitemapLink,
    // ...
}) => {
    const selectedLogoUrl = useLogoImageUrl(logoImageUrl);

    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const splitMenuData = menu?.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
        const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index / 2);
        if (!acc[chunkIndex]) {
            acc[chunkIndex] = [];
        }
        acc[chunkIndex].push(item);
        return acc;
    }, []);

    return (
        <footer>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="/" aria-label='logo'>
                            <img src={selectedLogoUrl} alt="Logo" />
                        </a>
                        <div>
                            {/* Some hardcoded links */}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {instagramLink && (
                                <a href={instagramLink} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
                                    <img src="/path/to/instagram.svg" alt="Instagram" />
                                </a>
                            )}
                            {/* ... */}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <nav>
                        {splitMenuData?.map(row =>
                            row.map(item => (
                                <Item item={item} key={item.id} />
                            ))
                        )}
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {sitemapLink && (
                            <li>
                                <a href={sitemapLink}>Sitemap</a>
                            </li>
                        )}
                        {/* ... */}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    );
};

and the Custom Hook code:
import {
    DEFAULT_LOGO_IMAGE_DARK_SRC,
    DEFAULT_HERO_IMAGE_LIGHT_SRC,
    STYLE_MODE_DARK,
} from '../constants';

export const useLogoImageUrl = ( path, styleMode ) => {
    const isDark = styleMode === STYLE_MODE_DARK;

    return (
        path ||
        ( isDark ? DEFAULT_HERO_IMAGE_LIGHT_SRC : DEFAULT_LOGO_IMAGE_DARK_SRC )
    );
};

I tried using the useMemo() hook in the component (where it shouldn't be!) and in the custom hook (where it should be!) like the following:
import { useMemo } from '@wordpress/element';
import {
    DEFAULT_LOGO_IMAGE_DARK_SRC,
    DEFAULT_HERO_IMAGE_LIGHT_SRC,
    STYLE_MODE_DARK,
} from '../constants';

export const useLogoImageUrl = ( path, styleMode ) => {
    console.log( styleMode );
    const isDark = 'dark' === STYLE_MODE_DARK;

    return useMemo( () => {
        return (
            path ||
            ( isDark
                ? DEFAULT_HERO_IMAGE_LIGHT_SRC
                : DEFAULT_LOGO_IMAGE_DARK_SRC )
        );
    }, [ path, isDark ] );
};

Also tried commenting the Item Component.
None of it removed the error.
If it's the chance the one reading this question knows about WordPress, one detail I didn't mention yet (because I believe is fully a React problem) is that this React Component is a WP Block and the error happens specifically when I save it as a Pattern (Inserting the block in the Page's Editor, and Selecting 'Create pattern' from the block's options).
If that's your case, here is a little more detail about what I tried in WordPress.
I repeat, I don't believe this is a WP problem, but pure React error. But I am giving all the details I digged in and know so that you can help me better.
Thanks!

Hello, can we also see the component that call Footer please ?

I fixed the error with the hint Lansana gave me in the first comment.
The problem was the component that was calling the Footer Component.
It had 3 useEffects:
    useEffect( () => {
        setAttributes( { statesMenu } );
    }, [ setAttributes, statesMenu ] );

    useEffect( () => {
        setAttributes( { states: statesMenu } );
    }, [ setAttributes, statesMenu ] );

    useEffect( () => {
        // cache the available options when choosign a new option
        // (for server-side rendering)
        // FIXME: 'Save' method of this block should be server-side
        // otherwise we're forced to refresh on client side
        // which could lead to SEO problems as menues get updated
        setAttributes( { menu } );
    }, [ setAttributes, menu ] );

changed it to:
    useEffect( () => {
        if ( statesMenu !== cachedStatesMenu ) {
            setAttributes( { statesMenu } );
        }
        if ( menu !== cachedMenu ) {
            setAttributes( { menu } );
        }
    }, [ setAttributes, statesMenu, menu ] );

and that fixed the Minified React error #185.
I am still having the problem I mentioned in the WordPress forum (post_content saves in null for this component only), but I believe that has to do with WordPress issue which no longer corresponds to this forum.
Thanks a lot!
